# How to Access Vue-Loader Components in an HTML File

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-loader

I would like to use the modular style and file format of Vue Loader (i.e., where I have a template section, script section and style section in each .vue file).

What I can't figure out how to do (or if it is even possible to do) is use my custom templates in an html file.

For instance, in the App.vue file I can use the following code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <message>Hello there</message>
  </div>
</template>
```

This will work to display a custom message component on the home page.

What I would like to do instead is use my custom components in html files.  For instance, in the index.html file to use the following code:

```
  <div id="app">
    <message>Hello there</message>
  </div>
```

Any idea how I can do this?  Thanks.

NOTE:  I am new to Vue Loader and semi-new to Vue (so I apologize in advance if the answer to this question is obvious).

Comment: It sounds like you want to write components using the single file component syntax, but use those components in Vues that you create in a script tag on an HTML page. Is that correct?

Comment: @BertEvans I think so.  Basically, I want to have an html page that makes a call to a single js file and renders the components within the normal flow of html using the custom component tag.  E.g. `<message>This is a message</message>`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can compile a single file component and then use that component in a web page.

### Use vue-cli

Vue released a command line interface tool called [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) that can initialize projects and build components with zero configuration. One option to build a component that you can use in your page is to use [vue build](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/master/docs/build.md).

```
vue build MyComponent.vue --prod --lib MyComponent
```

This will compile a script that exposes MyComponent. If you include that script in your page and then add it globally,

```
Vue.component(MyComponent)
```

That component will be available to you in any of your Vues.

### Make a plugin

Here is a sample of a very basic framework for making a plugin.

**myPluginDefinition.js**

```
window.MyPlugin= {};

MyPlugin.install = function (Vue) {
    Vue.component('my-component', require('./my-component.vue'));
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./myPluginDefinition.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname+'/dist',
        filename: "MyPlugin.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader',
        }
        ]
    }
};
```

This will build a file called `MyPlugin.js` that will contain each of the single file components that you include in the install function. Include the script on your page and then call

```
Vue.use(MyPlugin)
```

and you will have all of your components.

### Use a custom webpack configuration

There are many ways you could configure webpack to build your single file components. You could build them all into a single file or build them separately. I suggest if you want to use one of these options you ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do this easily by:

**register your component :**

```
Vue.component('message', {
    template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
});
```

**then comment the `render` function in your `Vue` instance like so:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  // render: h => h(App)
})
```

**after that you will be able to render your message Tag like this:**

```
<div id="app">
      <message></message>
</div>
```

**Edit** :
if you don't want to use this way you can define it in your view instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  // render: h => h(App)
  components: {
    message: {
     template: `
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
        `
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: What I want to do, though, is use `<template></template>` rather than use `Vue.component...`.

Comment: check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) however it will require a lot of js code. I have updated my answer so if you want to register your component in vue instance.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying that `Vue.component('message', {
    template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
});`  will render to a smaller js file than having a message.vue file with the following code `<template><divA custom component!</div></template>` which I then import as follows `import Message from './message.vue'`.  Is that right?

Comment: if you use `Vue.Component` then this component will be a available throughout all your application which you can render it wherever you want However if you register it for example in another component this will be available only for the component  it has been registered in. and what meant when i said if you want to create a template without using the `vue` framework or any framework that will require alot of vanilla js code since that what the frameworks are doing for  us.

Answer (score 0):

## Import desired component definition object and pass it to `options.components`

```
<template>
    <some-component></some-component>
</template>
<style>...</style>
<script>
    import SomeComponent from 'path/to/some-component.vue';

    export default {
        components: {
            // ES2015 shorthand for SomeComponent: SomeComponent
            SomeComponent
        }
    }
</script>
```

That leverages [local component registration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Local-Registration)

Both the default export and `SomeComponent` are component definition objects.