# How to integrate Vue components in normal HTML or JSP file

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Via the [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) I have craeted a [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) app. And in this app I have a developed a component around an [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo) graph. This component I have named  `BoilerGraph` and in the `App.vue` file I can use it like this:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <BoilerGraph period="2016" subtitle="Problem Year"></BoilerGraph>
        <BoilerGraph period="2019" ></BoilerGraph>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import BoilerGraph from './components/BoilerGraph'

    export default {
        name: 'app',
        components: {
            BoilerGraph
        }
    }
</script>
```

So far so good, but how can I use the component `BoilerGraph` in a "normal" standalone HTML file (or for that matter in a JSP file)? What files (and in what order) do I have to link into the HTML file via the usual `<link href="...` tag lines?

Or if these script files don't exist separately by default (a normal `vue build` seem to compress everything into one `dist.js` file), how can I instruct vue or webpack to create exactly the files I can link into a normal HTML file in order to use there the `BoilerGraph` component?

**Note:** I saw the question [How to Access Vue-Loader Components in an HTML File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098233/how-to-access-vue-loader-components-in-an-html-file) but the answers only seem to show how to generate a vue component *for a vue app*, *not for a normal HTML file*. I want to find out which JavaScript files I have to link into the standalone HTML file to use my component there.

Comment: You can generate [web components](https://www.webcomponents.org/introduction) from Vue components using the [@vue/web-component-wrapper](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-web-component-wrapper) library, check [this guide](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/05/21/vue-js-web-component/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to used vue in the standalone HTML file. I guessed you can not used SPA structure to achieved your goal. Instead, you should use html template and import vue from CDN.

```
<div id="app">
  <BoilerGraph period="2016" subtitle="Problem Year"></BoilerGraph>
  <BoilerGraph period="2019" ></BoilerGraph>
</div>    

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.8/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="BoilerGraph">
  <div class="BoilerGraph">your BoilerGraph template at here!</div>
</script>

<script>
  Vue.component('BoilerGraph', {
    template: '#BoilerGraph',
    props: ... // Your other props need to pass
  });

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However I don't understand what goes in at "*your BoilerGraph template at here*". My  `BoilerGraph` component contains a **template** part, a **script** part and a **style** part - all bundled in a `.vue` file. Can I somehow tell vue/webpack to convert that into a normal Javascript file to be included?

Comment: "your BoilerGraph template at here" means you should put your template part in here. However, i think CMS's comments is the best answer for you. It seems you can convert vue component to .js file by using [@vue/web-component-wrapper library](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-web-component-wrapper). Therefore, you can use it in html file directly.

Comment: The link by CMS mentions that "in this way, you can add your vue component into your non-vuejs project". However, my project is a standalone vuejs 2.0 library. Will I be able to use the events clicked within this wrapped-component into the vue js structure of this page (methods, computed, etc)?

Comment: `Vue.component('BoilerGraph'`  the name should be `boilergraph`, no upercase.  Otherwise, `<BoilerGraph></BoilerGraph>` should be `<boiler-graph></boiler-graph>`

Answer (score 0):

a more tangible example based on @bcjohn

```
<div id="app">
    <boiler-graph period="2016" subtitle="Problem Year"></boiler-graph>
    <boiler-graph period="2019"></boiler-graph>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="BoilerGraph">
  <div class="BoilerGraph">{{period}} - {{subtitle}}</div>
</script>


<scrpt>
        Vue.component('BoilerGraph', { 
            template: '#BoilerGraph',
            props: ['period','subtitle']
        });

        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
        })
</script>
```