# Unable to access vue component from a jsp page

Tags: jsp, vue.js

I'm trying to implement a vue component in my jsp page. I have tried to access a js file having import, export statement(s) using type="module" to script tag and file has been successfully loaded and executed. but when executing the import statement in that js file, it's returning below error in console :

**Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.**

Below is my jsp code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<script type="module" src="../../../../js/serviceMap/packages/AssignList/index.js"></script>
```

Below is the piece of code in js file

```
import OpsAssignList from './src/AssignList.vue'

OpsAssignList.install = function install(Vue) {
  Vue.component(OpsAssignList.name, OpsAssignList)
};

export default OpsAssignList
```

Note : I would like to use my vue-component in my existing jsp page and as well as our standalone project. So i'm trying to access the vue component using js file consisting of importing the component etc.

How can achieve both using this procedure ? got struck in my development activities.

[Attached the image of browser console for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaWP8.png)

Comment: This link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54964965/how-to-integrate-vue-components-in-normal-html-or-jsp-file

Comment: i'm trying to initialize vue component in my jsp page using external script(i.e. js file having ES6 statements i.e. import) ......but in the above provided link, they are doing it using script tag.

btw thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you loading Vue as like this.

```
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.8/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Then you have to keep all in .js files. Dont write import statements.Even webpack will do same process after build all es6 will convert to js and it will include in kind of app.87cbdfb9.js

```
   <script src="/your-app/js/app.87cbdfb9.js"></script>
```

And this will include in your main index.html file like above

** For Standalone without webpack *** 
then follow like this

```
<html>
<body>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

 <!-- templates for your components -->
  <template id="assign-list">
    <div>test</div>
  </template>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.0.1/dist/vue-router.js"></script> 

      <!-- Your Vue Root component should be last -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/AssignList.js"></script> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

Your AssignList.js file should like

```
var AssignList = Vue.component('assign-list',
  {
    template: '#assign-list', // should match the ID of template tag
    data: function()
    {

    },
    methods:
    {
    }
  });
```

Comment: I'm trying to use my vue file for present jsp project and as well as for my standalone vue project. I can able to access that component using that .vue file in my standalone project but unable to use it in my jsp page. How can i use that .vue file successfully in my jsp file(so that i need not to maintain in 2 files for my 2 projects ?

This is my main issue. trying to solve since 2 weeks.(tried some other way called "http-vue-loader" but still i'm un-successful.[ source : https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader ])

Could you please help me out from this. thanks